# Getting PHP running on XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I installed `XAMPP for Windows` on my computer.  I started it up and checked the status and it said that `PHP` is activated.  I then went to the following directory: `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` and created a file name `phpinfo.php` with the following in it:

```
    <?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

I then opened my web browser (I tried `Internet Explorer` and `Google Chrome`) and typed in:

```
    http://localhost/phpinfo.php
```

in the address bar.  I got the following error:

```
Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. 
If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404 localhost 11/10/12 10:03:28 Apache/2.2.21 (Win32)
mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e PHP/5.3.8 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1**
```

If I just type in `http://localhost/`, I get the `XAMPP startup page` just fine.

I double and triple checked that my `phpinfo.php` is in the correct directory and am at a los for what else I could be doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`C:\inetpub\wwwroot` --> **Not** the default directory for Xampp. That is for IIS

`C:\xampp\htdocs\` --> default directory.

---

Create `xyz.php` within `C:\xampp\htdocs\` and then access `http://localhost/xyz.php`.

Comment: Yep!  That did it.  I need to learn to read the documentation correctly!!!!  Thanks for answering a dumb question quickly